# Ajax append result and animate

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, append

I'm trying to append ajax data and slideDown Ajax result data (something like twitter load more)

Tried following code

```
$("#main").append(html).slideDown();
```

but data appears without any animation.

How can I append and animate html data from PHP side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that yoou want to slideDown newly created element instead of #main.
Thy this.

```
$(html).css('display','none').appendTo($("#main")).slideDown();
```

Comment: This still won't work.  The content will be visible as soon as you append it to `#main`.

Comment: as GregL said, your element should be invisible first. $(html).css('display','none').appendTo($("#main")).slideDown();

Comment: This will not work with all content in `html`.  Bare text, for instance, will not work.  Also, if `html` does not have one parent wrapper, each element will `slideDown` individually.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/kDsjL/1/

Comment: slideDown function need the inner element to be a block element, if it is a float element such as <span> or nothing, it will not works.

Answer (score 2):

`.slideDown()` animates elements which are hidden, as they appear.  Because I assume that `#main` is already visible, when you append items to it, they will simply show up.

What you need to do is append your content to a hidden div at the bottom of `#main` and call `.slideDown()` on that hidden div.

If you want to do this repeatedly, you would call `.unwrap()` in your callback so that you can add the hidden element later:

```
$('#myHiddenDiv').slideDown("slow", function() {
   $(this).children().unwrap();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6VQwb/1/

Comment: Please create chatroom so we can discuss it. I wanna show you page in action. thx in advance.

Comment: Chatroom is [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8557/ajax-append-result-and-animate) if you wanted to join, Jeff.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to `.hide()` the container before appending to it and sliding it down.

The call to `.hide()` will set the CSS style to `display: none;`, which will mean appending the content doesn't show anything until it starts to slide down.

So:

```
$('#main').hide().append(html).slideDown();
```

As for how to append and animate HTML data from the PHP side, you'll want to follow a similar strategy - use PHP to insert the content into a `<div>` with a style of `display: none;`, then use jQuery to slide it down.

Comment: I don't want to hide parent - #main div. I want to animate result

Comment: It will animate the result - it first hides the content of the div, so that slideDown can transition it from being completely hidden to having more and more height until it completes. Does that make sense? See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fHAzX/) for proof of how it works.

Comment: Please create chatroom so we can discuss it. I wanna show you page in action. thx in advance.

Comment: Chatroom should be here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/8557/ajax-append-result-and-animate?tab=general